# How would one get a "motion score" in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

I need a number that would indicate how much a scene is moving, either in the foreground or background.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most simple way would be:

```
   Mat currentFrame, lastFrame, diff;
   absdiff( currentFrame, lastFrame, diff );
   float n = norm(diff, CV_NORM_L2);
   lastFrame = currentFrame.clone();
```

here, n is a measure for the difference beween this and the last frame

maybe you even want optical flow, which gives you a movement vector per pixel:

```
  // convert to grayscale before ..
  //
  Mat flow;      
  calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prevgray, gray, flow, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0);
  // 
  // flow is a CV_32FC2 matrix, each "pixel" is a Point2f with x,y being the motion gradient for that
```

position

(there's a [demo](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/samples/cpp/fback.cpp) for that, too)

Comment: Thank you sir! I will try this now and see whether the resulting number's magnitude corresponds approximately to what my brain thinks of "motion"

Comment: if you can pseudocode the optical flow option as well, I would be eternally grateful and instantly accept your answer! :)